# Can't remote desktop to an XP machine to login

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

I have an XP machine which I want to access using RDP. The problem is until I log this machine into Windows, I can't get an RDP connection. Do I have to trick the PC into logging in at startup?

Comment: What is the error/What do you see when you try to log in?

Comment: @Wil edited. It's fine once I log in but the question was if I can avoid this part.

Comment: Possibly wait a bit longer? It is possible that your NIC is acquiring an IP or similar. What happens? Do you just get no connection/error message or time out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not correct, Remote Desktop (Not Remote Assistance) should work from the moment the machine is loaded and in Windows. I use it all the time on remote machines.

(If you edit your question, I will update this with an answer to help..)

VNC is typically installed in User Mode and does not allow interaction at the login screen.

[Logmein Free](https://secure.logmein.com/UK/products/free/) is the only non corporate (free) solution I know of that works from the login screen.

Comment: Teamviewer also allows access from the login screen, and is free for personal use.

Comment: @Kyle - is that the unattended mode? (Seen the option, never looked in to it...)

Comment: yep it is under the options for unattended access, I believe they referred to it as unattended mode in older versions of teamviewer (4 and below). Either way it's a nice feature and allows it to compete with logmein.